# Calculate AVERAGE in SAS

Tags: sas, average

I have been using `proc means` to get an average *copay* out of my dataset for a particular month, but I also need to calculate average *copay* by *pharmacy*.

It doesn't seem like I can do this with `proc means`, also I prefer it as a dataset I can query off of, not a `proc print` of 200 pharmacies. I tried the below code but I'm not getting the same numbers as I would with `proc means`:

This is how I sum data by Pharmacy, is there a way to make this an average by pharmacy instead of summing it?:

```
    %pjsum(add_ram,  RAM      pme_id pharmacy month, patient_benefit APPR, sum);
```

Comment: *I tried the below code but I'm not getting the same numbers* ... of course because a data step is not the same as proc means. Please show input data for a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what is proc means doing that I can't do in a data step? I guess what's the difference, it's really hard to find stuff online for this.

Comment: Consider reading [SAS support docs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#means-overview.htm). Succinctly put, `proc means` aggregates data while data step runs rowwise and columnwise calculations including merges and appends. Here you are only assigning new columns. No averages are run.

Comment: is there a way to calculate averages in a datastep? a function for it?

Comment: As commented above, please provide sample data or even random data so we can see your columns.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code, perhaps that's more helpful...

Comment: Now you have no code. Just a call to macro that you have not shown the source code for.

Comment: I don't understand the question. PROC MEANS can generate a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a *patient_benefit* numeric column and *pharmacy* and *month* columns, you can use `proc means` by specifying groups in *class* and numeric column in *var* clauses. Be sure to specify the *mean* statistic. Below outputs a dataset named *AggData* with *Avg_Patient_Benefit* as the aggregated column.

```
proc means data=myData nway ;
  class pharmacy month;
  var patient_benefit;
  output out=AggData mean=Avg_Patient_Benefit;  
run;
```

Alternatively you can run an aggregate SQL query with `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
   create table AggData as
   select pharmacy, month, mean(patient_benefit)
   from myData
   group by pharmacy, month;
quit;
```

You can even run conditional aggregation for various month columns:

```
proc sql;
   create table AggData as
   select pharmacy, 
          mean(case when month = "July" then patient_benefit else . end) as avg_july_month,
          mean(case when month = "August" then patient_benefit else . end) as avg_aug_month,
          mean(case when month = "September" then patient_benefit else . end) as avg_sep_month
          ...
   from myData
   group by pharmacy;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you SO much!  I went with the middle one, but were all great, I really appreciate it!